# Delay between two XBee End-Points (attached to RPi's) when told to collect data from XBee Coordinator (attached to a PC)

Tags: raspberry-pi, delay, latency, xbee

Currently have 3 XBee S1 Modules in play.

One is set up as a Coordinator (API mode) and is connected to a laptop via a USB-adapter.
The other two are set up as End-Points (AT mode) and are connected to 2 Raspberry Pi's Model 3 B.

Both RPi's have an ADXL345 accelerometer attached to them in order to collect vibration data. 
It's important for our model that both RPi's start collecting data at the same time (within 10 ms of eachother).

We have set up a Frame List in XCTU so we through our Coordinator can, via a python script on the RPi's, start the collection of data.

Currently we are able to start collecting data within 0,5 seconds of eachother. So there is some kind of time stamp problem in our setup.
It seems like XBee End-Point 1 receives the given commands before XBee End-Point 2.

So our problem is that the data collected from End-Point 1 always seem around 0,4-0,6 seconds ahead of End-Point 2.
It happens both when we start and stop the data collection. So End-Point 1 also stops 0,4-0,6 seconds before End-Point 2.

If needed I can provide more information. Just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the setup you have, you will need another protocol implemented at the application layer which synchronises the clocks on each device and then define a starting point for both PIs. One common approach is to use an [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) which synchronises the clocks on the nodes with an external clock (probably you can use your laptop's clock). In addition to this you have the communication time between the PIs and the latop. For instance from the PIs you send a synchronisation request. Then this message is received on the laptop and send back with the current time. You need to account for this delay.

This is difficult to calculate precisely. What you can do in your current setup is to run some experiments by sending messages between the PIs and the laptop to estimate the communication delay. By running a number of experiments you can estimate the mean and the standard deviation. You use these values to improve the accuracy of the synchronisation. After this step, the command to start recording sensing values can be initiated at a certain point in time.